# change SharePoint logo?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I want to change SharePoint logo to my deportment logo, and also change some layout styles (like colors). I want to find an easy to follow tutorial.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Why belongs to superuser, it is a server related question? :-)

Comment: Because it's to do with using the product, not its administration or infrastructure. (Thanks for the accept!)

Comment: I disagree - that is the sort of change an administrator is likely to make centrally for the whole system.  I speak as a Sharepoint admin.  Leave the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Click **Site Actions**, **Site Settings**, **Modify All Site Settings**.
2. Click **Title, description and icon** under Look and Feel.
3. Change the URL for Logo URL and Description.

The URL can be anything as long as it's accessible from the browser. People often upload their site logo to a document or picture library and use the URL for that.

Answer (score 2):

[Heather Solomon's blog](http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm) is awesome for styling Sharepoint 2007 (and 2003) - changing colours can be done through themes, but you can also manually change the core.css (do a backup first) to change your colour scheme. I'd advise using developer tools in your browser to find the actual css tags that you'll need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Create your new logo - MyLogo.gif. Save it, on the server file structure, in the 12 hive. /12/TEMPLATES/IMAGES/MyLogo.gif. Same folder where all the other SP images are held.
On the new Master page template, point the top left graphic (titlegraphic.gif) at your new image, MyLogo.gif.
If you have multiple front ends, place that same image on all applicable.

Answer (score -2):

[This MS tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepointtechnology/HA011228651033.aspx) shows you how to do all of that.

Comment: The tutorial applies to WSS 2.0 and contains steps that do not work for WSS 3.0 / SharePoint 2007.